# Rails render multiple pdf files to a folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, prawn

I have a controller action that renders a pdf for download.
I want to render multiple pdfs to a tmp folder ( then zip them for download )

I can generate the pdfs and present to the user but I can't figure out how to create a folder to store them in.

I'm using prawn. It has the `render_file` method to save it to the filesystem but I don't know what directory it is or if other users could save their pdf's to the same folder, so I need to create a uniques folder for each user then save the pdf's there.

How can I do this?

my controller action is currently

```
def showpdf
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        @items.each do |pdf|
          pdf = Prawn::Document.new(page_size:  "A4",margin: [0,0,0,0])

         # pdf creation stuff...

          # this was used previously to render one pdf to the browser
          # but I need to save multiple pdf's
          #send_data pdf.render, filename: 'report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Looks like you need some sort of combination of Dir.mktmpdir or Tempfile.new depending on how you will iterate through the files and pass them to the zip utility.

Comment: @depquid that is what I'm asking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to store all files into tmp/your-folder folder, something like this

```
require 'prawn'
@items.each do |item|
   pdf = Prawn::Document.new
   pdf.text("Lets Zip All.")
   pdf.render_file('tmp/your-folder/#{item.id}.pdf')
end
```

and then simply use https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip to zip the your-folder.

```
require 'zip'
folder = "tmp/your-folder/"
zipfile_name = "tmp/archive.zip"

input_filenames = Dir.entries("tmp/your-folder/").select {|f| !File.directory? f} 

Zip::File.open(zipfile_name, Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
  input_filenames.each do |filename|
  zipfile.add(filename, folder + '/' + filename)
end

zipfile.get_output_stream("myFile") { |os| os.write "myFile contains just this" }
end
```

Simply send the file to user. But if the PDF contains a lot of data move them to delayed jobs. 
Hope this makes sense but if not please hit reply.

Comment: thanks but the final section doesn't seem to be working, the line `zipfile.add(filename, folder + '/' + filename)` throws the error `No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /myfilename.pdf` , is that the correct way to join folder & filename into a path?

Comment: it needed to be ` File.join(folder, filename)`   how do I present the zip file for download now that it's generated?

Comment: to answer my own last question `send_file(File.join(folder, 'archive.zip'), :type => 'application/zip', :filename => 'archive.zip')`

Comment: Sorry for that, i was just writing code without running it and live in Asia so could not response earlier. Great that was missing part.